# Import two js, the above file does not appear to be executed, and the following one is executed successfully，why？

Tags: electron

Look，two script tag,the top js isn't useful, the bottom js is useful, and so is switching places,the top isnt useful.No error reported.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <button id="yellowWin">create new window</button>
</body>

<script src="../../src/main/rightClick.js"></script>
<script src="../../src/render/yellowWin.js"></script>

</html>
```

I can't understand,please help me,thank you.

rightClick.js is to right-click menu, yellowWin.js is to click the button to create a new window, they both call the @electron/remote module.

rightClick.js:

```js
const {Menu} = require('@electron/remote')
const currentWindow = require('@electron/remote').getCurrentWindow();
const template = [
    {
        label: 'Copy',
        accelerator: 'ctrl+c',
        click: () => {
            console.log('复制');
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Cut',
        accelerator: 'ctrl+x',
        click: () => {
            console.log('剪切');
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Paste',
        accelerator: 'ctrl+v',
        click: () => {
            console.log('粘贴');
        }
    }
];
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
window.onload = () => {
    window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.popup({window: currentWindow});
        console.log('右键');
    }, false)
}
```

**yellowWin.js:**

```js
const {BrowserWindow} = require('@electron/remote')

const yellowWin = document.getElementById('yellowWin');

window.onload = ()=> {
    yellowWin.onclick =  ()=> {
        let newWin = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 400,
            height: 200
        })
        newWin.loadFile('static/index/yellow.html')
        newWin.on('closed', () => {
            newWin = null
        })
        console.log('yellowWin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron comes with different [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) features, which are activated by default. And for security reasons, you should keep NodeJS and Electron-related code on the main process, and not try to import it on your renderer process like you do here. Finally, using `@electron/remote` module is unnecessary, as you can already do the same with the native API of Electron.

Now, for your particular case, what you need to use is [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) to communicate between the renderer and the main processes. If you want to create a new window on button click for example:

**index.html**

```html
<!-- Remove these:

<script src="../../src/main/rightClick.js"></script>
<script src="../../src/render/yellowWin.js"></script>

Add a new script: -->

<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

**renderer.js**

```js
const { electronAPI } = window; // Gets the API exposed with `contextBridge`
const yellowWin = document.getElementById('yellowWin');

yellowWin.addEventListener("click", electronAPI.createWindow);
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  createWindow: () => ipcRenderer.send('create-window')
});
```

**main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // [...] Code to create your main window,
  // don't forget to link the preload file with `webPreferences.preload`

  ipcMain.on('create-window', () => {
    // [...] Code to create the new window
  });
});
```

Further detailed examples are available [in the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc), I suggest you read them carefully as all the information you need are here. If you struggle to understand IPC, I suggest you take a look at [this article](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/), which explain very well how everything works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instruction, I have given up using the @electron/remote module in favor of a secure preloader.
I wish you good health and success in your career!